# Prevent Key Event on DevExress ASP.NET MVC SpinEdit

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, devexpress

In a form, I have a spin edit control like this:

```
formLayoutSettings.Items.Add(i =>
{
    i.FieldName = "FieldA";
    i.NestedExtension().SpinEdit(s =>
    {
        s.Properties.MinValue = 1;
        s.Properties.MaxValue = 9999999999999;
        s.Properties.ValidationSettings.ErrorDisplayMode = ErrorDisplayMode.ImageWithTooltip;
        s.Properties.ClientInstanceName = "seFieldA";
        s.Properties.Increment = 10;
        s.ShowModelErrors = true;
        s.Width = Unit.Percentage(100);
        s.Properties.AllowMouseWheel = false;
        s.Properties.ClientSideEvents.KeyDown = "OnFieldAKeyDown"; // This is the event heandeler
    });
});
```

And the function:

```
function OnFieldAKeyDown(s, e) {
    if (e.htmlEvent.keyCode == 38 || e.htmlEvent.keyCode == 40) {
        ASPxClientUtils.PreventEventAndBubble(e.htmlEvent); // this doesn't work
        ASPxClientUtils.PreventEvent(e.htmlEvent); // this either
    }
}
```

My aim is to prevent the spin edit control value from changing when the user presses the Up key or Down keys. When I debug this, the if test inside the OnFieldAKeyDown works but PreventEventAndBubble and PreventEvent fails miserably. Also, is there any other way to do this with jquery ??

Thanks.

Comment: why you dont use a textbox intead of spinedit? with a regular expression? `[RegularExpression("([1-9][0-9]*)", ErrorMessage = "Count must be a natural number")]
public int Count { get; set; }`

Comment: Because the client asked specifically for a spin edit.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, there is a workaround to prevent a user incrementing/decrementing `SpinEdit` value using up/down arrow keys without using `PreventEvent` or `PreventEventAndBubble`. When there's no public method available on JS side, you can try restore `SpinEdit` previous value in `KeyDown` event handler like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function OnFieldAKeyDown(s, e) {
    if (e.htmlEvent.keyCode == 38 || e.htmlEvent.keyCode == 40) {

       // check if ASPxClientSpinEdit exists
       if (typeof ASPxClientSpinEdit !== "undefined") {
           ASPxClientSpinEdit.prototype.OnPageOrArrowKeyDown = function() {
               // when user tries either increment or decrement, it returns last value instead
               if (s.GetValue() != s.lastChangedValue) {
                   s.SetValue(s.lastChangedValue);
               }
               // if spinedit's minimum & maximum values also affected, set current limit
               else {
                   s.maxValue = ASPxClientSpinEdit.MaxValue;
                   s.minValue = ASPxClientSpinEdit.MinValue;
               }
           }
       }
    }
}
</script>
```

Combine this function with jQuery may possible, any suggestions welcome.

Reference: https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q254514

Comment: Nice workaround :) but this disables the spin buttons, is there anyway to do it without affecting the spin buttons ?? Thanks